# How can we concatenate function without calling it like in d3.svg.line.radial

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I want to know how we can concatenate methods calls without calling them (I mean  without using the `()` ).

For example, I know that if the method of my object returns the object, I can concatenate methods like in jQuery :

```
$(myelement).attr('id','hello').addClass('my-class').etc(...
```

But I've seen in `jasmine test framework` or in `d3.js` that they concat objects with methods without calling them, like  :

```
d3.svg.line.radial().etc(...
```

I first thought it was as easy as `d3` is an `object`, `.svg` too, `.line` too, etc...

But if I take a look at [d3.js's source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/line.js), or simply type in the dev tools console :

```
d3.svg.line
```

it say's that line is a function...

```
function(){return ho(y)}
```

So can anybody tell me what magic transforms `line` from a `function` to an `object` if I concatenate it with with a new `object`/`method` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function can also have properties:

```
var start = {};

start.middle = function(){
    return "Middle";
}

start.middle.end = function(){
    return "End";
}
```

So now `start.middle()` returns `"Middle"` and `start.middle.end()` returns `"End"`

Comment: I'm ashamed that I never noticed this... Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the difference here is:

- d3 are functions. Concatenated functions normally will use the parent as a dependency. [`line.radial()` will use line `"module"`]
- If you concatenate functions calling them you will be able to choose the order and construct your call stacks, applying those functions in the way you want.

*For example:*
You want to create a finite red line:

- d3 approach: `line.segment(x,y,red);`
- calling functions:  `line(x,y).color(red).cutEdges();` or `line(x,y).cutEdges().color(red);`

**You should chose what do you want in your application, is not only the way it looks.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not really what I asked for.